# Alternative to FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

Is there an alternative for selecting folders in C#?

Optimally I'd like to use the OpenFileDialog to select folders, or at least something similar to that.

Comment: You want an alternative to the FolderBrowserDialog that is built into Winforms, but when given two alternatives, you state that you want something built-in..

Comment: **[Ookii Dialogs](https://github.com/ookii-dialogs)** libraries have an implementation of a folder browser dialog for Windows Forms and WPF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have and [OpenFileOrFolder](https://github.com/scottwis/OpenFileOrFolderDialog) dialog and here another [FolderBrowserDialog](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) both Open Source.

Comment: That Ookii dialog works really well. Just curious, but is there any non-third alternatives to FolderBrowserDialog? I was hoping there would be a moderately easy way of having an OpenFileDialog that allows you to select folders.

Comment: @NMunro Nop. The BCL doesn't provide you with other alternative. But implemented third-party ones isn't as hard as it seems.

Comment: I already got the implementation to work with Ookii, but I'd prefer not to use a 3rd party app.

Answer (score 4):

**[Ookii Dialogs](https://github.com/ookii-dialogs)** libraries have an implementation of a folder browser dialog for Windows Forms and WPF

[image: Ookii Folder Browser Dialog]

> **Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms**
>
> https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-winforms

---

> **Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf**
>
> https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf

Answer (score 3):

For this very reason I developed [BetterFolderBrowser](https://github.com/Willy-Kimura/BetterFolderBrowser). It's a .NET library does just what you need by providing an easy-to-use folder browsing experience that mimics the `OpenFileDialog` dialog window. Also, since it works as a component, you'll be able to easily tweak its properties in Design Mode. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I found myself to what you may want is this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15059/C-File-Browser

This is a control that you can place on a dialog (form). It allows selecting files or folders. Here is what my implementation looks like:

[image]

Comment: The Ookii dialog that was posted earlier is almost exactly what I want. It's essentially the openfiledialog, but for folders. Only I'd prefer not to use a third party app.