# Directory Chooser without Forms FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, directory, selection

for my C# WPF project I need a Folder Selection Dialog. Because it is neccesary that the user is able to see the content of the folders while browsing to choose the correct one, I am not able to use the Win Forms FolderBrowserDialog, which does not show the content.
External packages might be also problematic.

I first thought this will be an easy task, keeps me struggeling for quite a while now.

Has anybody a great idea to implement it without creating my own usercontrol.

Thanks al lot in advance

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders)?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: A simple usercontrol with treeview for folders and some listview (in details mode?) to show files should do. For alternatives see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12461016/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

A "solution" without external packages, without rolling your own control and without P/Invoke-stuff, but more of a horrible workaround:

```
//using System.Windows.Forms;

OpenFileDialog ofp = new OpenFileDialog();
ofp.FileName = "The file will be ignored";
ofp.CheckFileExists = false;
ofp.CheckPathExists = true;
ofp.ValidateNames = false;
```

Simply put, a non-existing file with the name `The file will be ignored` will be selected from the dialog. As `CheckFileExists` is false, this won't be a problem and you can just read the chosen directory.
In other words: the user can select any file he/she wants.

I don't recommend using this. It's quite horrible (in style and for the user), but this is the most simple way to achieve what you want.  Personally, I would go all the way and implement my own control or - even better - use a third-party control. There are a few out there who do this.

There is no support for this out-of-the-box. With the standard dialogs you can either see files, but not select folders or the other way round.