# Can making a new folder be done under a specific dir. using FolderBrowserDialog class

Tags: c#, directory

I'm using the FolderBrowserDialog class to allow a user to select a directory however if they want to create a director, I only want to allow it to be created under a specific directory. Can this be done with this class? my current code looks like this:

```
FolderBrowserDialog diag = new FolderBrowserDialog();
     diag.SelectedPath = PubVars.locVault;
     diag.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
     DialogResult results = diag.ShowDialog();
     if (results.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
     {
        lblNewVault.Text = diag.SelectedPath;
        Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = diag.RootFolder;
     }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: AFAIK No, FolderBrowserDialog is so minimal that is pretty impossible to use it for something different from what has been (poorly) designed

Comment: Is there another class or API that would allow me to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: None that I know of. Of course using the Windows API anything is possible, but with the NET libraries I am not aware of anything that could do what you require. [There are alternatives to FolderBrowserDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461016/alternative-to-folderbrowserdialog) but they don't solve your requirements