# Change design of FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using `FolderBrowserDialog` from Windows Forms to open up a dialog so that user can choose a custom folder. Unfortunately, the `FolderBrowserDialog` has some arhaic design which gives users no option to paste a path.  Currently it looks similar to this:

[image]

I am after something with an option to paste path:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
using (var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog()) {
   string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
   dialog.SelectedPath = Global.DestinationFolder;
   System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: if you move to .net core - that is an option to enable

Comment: Alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461016/alternative-to-folderbrowserdialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot customize the `FolderBrowserDialog` from Windows Forms like that.
Once there was the `WindowsAPICodePack` that included the `CommonOpenFileDialog`, which had an option for folder selection that would display exactly the dialog you want, but it is not available anymore. You can still use it via the *unofficial* `WindowsAPICodePack-Shell` [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/).

```
var folderBrowser = new CommonOpenFileDialog { IsFolderPicker = true }
```

Another option is to move to .NET Core >= 3.0, where the `FolderBrowserDialog` in Windows Forms [was modernized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/fx-core#modernization-of-the-folderbrowserdialog). You need to add Windows Forms to your WPF project to be able to access it.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Finally, if there are no other alternatives, you can use native code to create an `IFileOpenDialog` and set its option to pick folders only. You can find general information about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776913(v=vs.85)).